# Why creating the front page doesn't work?

Tags: 7, theming

I created the file named page--front.tpl.php, which is empty, in the Garland theme and set the front end to it. I still can access the front page: why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you cleared the cache after you added the new template file in the theme directory? You should always clear the cache, once you change a template file for a theme already installed, or you add a new file that was not used before.

Comment: no, got it.when i clear the cache,it's ok. thank you.